# How to apply a useful uniform to my human mercenaries?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Now that I can get mercenaries in my military as <s>meat shields</s> <s>suicide</s> a spearhead squad, I need them to be able to receive some blows and not die. That's fine for dorfs mercs, but if I assign the human ones to a squad that uses a uniform, they end up naked; they like it, but I don't.

So, I started hunting "large ---" items one by one to arm them, **since I have tons of large armor already**, but this is proving inefficient in the long run (and a pain in the short one). Is there an easier way to uniform them? I have armors of all kinds, because dwarfs have been at war with everyone from year 1.

TL;dr: I have tons armor (and can create more) but using the UI for uniforms in the military doesn't allow me to select these.

Comment: Does [this](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Mercenary) help? "To forge equipment sized for non-dwarves, go to the workshop producing armor (this works for clothing, leather armor, and metal armor), move the cursor to the job producing armor, press details and select the race involved. You can find the desired race more easily by using the filter. This will change the produced armor's size to the selected creature's size."

Comment: @TimmyJim as I said on the question "I have armors of all kinds". The problem is not the existence of armors, but how to allow humans to be armored with them, instead of going commando.

Comment: I saw that you said that, I wasn't sure if doing what I said would have an option to clothe them or something (I don't have the game so I don't know).

Comment: Which version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements:**

1. Look if the item you want to equip has a ownership. You can forbid it for a 
   while to release it and someone else can equip it. Even if nobody is wearing 
   they don't wear equipment from others.
2. Mercenaries are just visitors when you accept them, and setting
   them to a squad you make them use that squad by default. If the
   armors you have as uniform aren't the same type of the ones in you collected 
   they will go naked.
3. It may take a while to them change their equipment, but if any member of the 
   squad stay naked you may need to issue and order to the squad to put them on 
   duty, being on duty makes them wear the uniform.

**From here you have a few paths to choose:**

- Change the squad uniform to some type you have plenty Large for humans.
- Create another squad with one dwarf as leader that fits the itens you have already.
- Set the equipment for individual choice
- Or

  > So, I started hunting "large ---" items ... Is there an easier way to uniform them?

  Do as @Timmy Jim said and set one of yours workshop to produce Large armor accordingly to your squad uniforms type.

**Sources and Helpful links:**

http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Armor#Purpose

http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Armor

http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Squad#Equipping_Soldiers

http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Mercenary

http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=164030.0

http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=155577.0

https://www.reddit.com/r/dwarffortress/comments/falu1/equipping_your_military/

Comment: The problem isn't, again, lack of stuff to wear, it's that I can't tell them to wear a specific type of uniform that is, well, useful. I have no guaranties that my mercs with will use breastplate armor, since if I tell them to use "breastplate", they will try to use dwarf sized ones.

Comment: Do you realized that I told you solutions for 3 different problems, and how the mechanics of the game works?

If the breastplate are owned by someone else, if they are not part of your inventory, if the item is not part of the uniform, if the equipment is not "fit for human", or if you don't want to set it as individual choice, I am sorry to say that there is no way to do it. Well unless you are using a version before 42.01 http://www.rpgcodex.net/forums/index.php?threads/dwarf-fortress-v0-42-01-released.105050/ so there is no way to  do that either.

Comment: btw, just in case you are using another version, check if the "partial matches / exact matches"  and the 'replace clothing/over clothing' choices. Those are thing that can affect some piece of armor like plate armor.

Comment: None of them are the ones I have. My question specifically states "useful uniform", and that means having a complete set of several pieces of wear with the same granularity as I have on dwarves. You don't explain any of that.

Comment: "human ones to a squad that uses a uniform, they end up naked; they like it, but I don't." - ownership, exact matches, replace clothing, uniform, armor size...
" Is there an easier way to uniform them? " yes, using the uniform template to a squad 
"I have tons armor (and can create more) but using the UI for uniforms in the military doesn't allow me to select these." If you tried the first steps you may have a bug and should report it.

If you refuse the games mechanics, 
refuse to answer peoples further investigation question, or you are playing a different game, or you are trolling us.

Comment: No. It's not ownership because dorft mercs doesn't have this problem. "using the uniform template to a squad" no, because if I want half the squad with graves instead of leggings there's no way to specify. They basically try to put on drorft sized clothes graves, which won't fit them and using "metal leggings" they could select any of them without any control other than micromanaging.